# Mono 4.2 on mac trying to build project with toolversion 4.0

Tags: c#, macos, c#-4.0, mono, xbuild

I am attempting to build a toolversion/targeversion 4.0 project using mono xbuild 4.2 on mac environment. I use the following command :

```
xbuild /tv:4.0
```

I can see in the compile error that it still appears to be using the default 4.5 toolversion :

> /usr/local/Cellar/mono/4.2.0.179/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.CSharp.targets
>   (CoreCompile target) ->
>
> Helpers/Formatters/TextMediaTypeFormatter.cs(20,32): error CS0115:

I have checked the .sln and csproj files they don't contain any references to 4.5, 
here is parts of the .csproj.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">   ...   <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    ...
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    ...
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    ...
```

The core of the problem is a MediaTypeFormatter overridden method that seems to have changed between 4.0 and 4.5 with its use of HttpContent and HttpContentHeaders,

I am hoping that by being able to set toolsversion or target version in the csproj or related files that I can have things building under mono.

I am new to C# and Mono so any insight on what I am doing wrong or other possible solutions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Updating to 4.5 tools/target/version is not an option due to project constraints.

Comment: Mono 4 drops all old profiles and stick to only 4.5 profile. I think that might be the cause. And you should now target 4.5 profile.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately targeting 4.5 profile is not an option, due to project constraints, really trying to find a way to force mono to build the 4.0 profile, I tried downgrading to an older version of mono but got the same issue.